# Pass multi T parameters in a method

Tags: c#

I wonder if i could create a method using multiple T parameters. Here is my method.

```
 public static void Dapper<T1, T2, T3, T4>()
 {
     using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conString))
     using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple("Select * from InventoryMaster;Select * from InventoryMaster", null))
     {
         var rows = multi.Read<T1>().ToList();
         var rows2 = multi.Read<T2>().ToList();            
     }
 }
```

I wonder if it is possible to pass List instead of <T1, T2, T3, T4>. I need to create a general method.  So T parameters are different in each case.

Comment: presumably the command and args would also need to be parameters; IMO by the time you've abstracted that, you've basically just created a thin wrapper on top of Dapper that adds nothing but forces multiple compromises; IMO it would have been easier (and more efficient) just to have each caller use Dapper directly. Can you clarify what you're actually trying to *achieve* here? But: is it possible? sort of: there's a `Read(Type type)` API, so you could pass in a `List<Type>`, but... that forces you to *create* a `List<Type>` each time, and ... is pretty ugly

Comment: I want to create a global method which I will pass models for multiple read using dapper

Comment: I would guess that 99% of your needs would be satisfied by having a couple of overloads - `<T1, T2>` , `<T1, T2, T3>` ,`<T1, T2, T3>` ,  etc; but even then: I'm not quite sure what you're gaining vs just having each caller use Dapper directly; perhaps another viable alternative would be to take an `Action<GridReader> action` to perform when the data is available, but... meh. I'd be intrigued to understand your scenario more, though (effectively, I *am* Dapper)

Comment: Can you add some examples to describe what you want to achieve. What you really want to pass in and how will you deal with the read data in different types.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you. I want to read and return multiple queries under the same connection. But also to use it as global method.

Comment: @dbsoft again, I think a few overloads for 1/2/3/4/5 types would satisfy almost all likely needs

Comment: @MarcGravell Probably i will follow this this way